# How to build a Python wheel for Opencv

Tags: python, linux, opencv, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I am a beginner in Python and I am looking for your help. So, I have built Opencv 4.4.0 from source with support for a few things (s.a. CUDA). I downloaded the package from here:

```
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.4.0.zip
```

Here is the command I used:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
    -D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
    -D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
    -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
    -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
    -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN="5.3" \
    -D CUDNN_VERSION='8.0' \
    -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3.7 \
    -D ENABLE_NEON=ON \
    -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
    -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=YES \
    -D EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/eigen3 \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

This is done on aarch64. After "make" and "make install" I got a file called "cv2.cpython-37m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so".

**Q1:**
Let us assume I format the SD card, can I simply use that file alone and get all the functionality I need?

**Q2**
[I read about creating ready packages via Python wheels](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). I want to create a wheel for my above built code. How can I do that? I searched a lot online but could not find a tutorial for that.

Thanks all!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python#manual-builds

Comment: That is a different package (opencv vs opencv-python). For example, I cannot run ```pip wheel .``` as they say in the build instructions because setup.py file is not there

Comment: The purpose of the package is only to build opencv wheels. I suggest you clone that repository, checkout the opencv and opencv_contrib submodules to the appropriate tag (i.e., `4.4.0`), add you extra cmake options to `$CMAKE_ARGS`, and then build with `pip wheel . --verbose`. That will produce an opencv wheel for you.