# Leveraging GPU with OpenCV 4.2

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use the GPU of my virtual machine with OpenCV library (4.2) and Python 3.7.

I have installed opencv with CUDA and the following command returns 1:

```
import cv2
count = cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()
print(count)
```

I tried to run my code with and without leveraging GPU:

```
start = time.time()
network = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(config_path, weights_path)
if IS_CUDA:
    network.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
    network.setPreferableTarget(cv.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
my_function(network, frame)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

But the running time is the same.

My question: Is using setPreferableBackend() and setPreferableTarget() enough to leverage GPU power ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, before runnning into code, you must check your working environement

What virtual machine are you using ? usually virtual machines does not support GPU virtualisation. You must add PCI-Passthrough to get this feature.

If true, can you first check that your device is successfully detected by running  `nvidia-smi` (within your favorite bash/cmd environment) in order to check your nvidia drivers.

Then check that your opencv-python supports your gpu by running in a python shell `cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()`

if the result is 0, and nvidia-smi detects your gpu, you must compile your python opencv wheel with the support of your specific gpu model and install it to your python environment.

Comment: => It's an Azure VM with GPU, specialized for AI inference (NCasT4_v3-series)

=>  How can I know if it has PCI Passthrough ? 

=> The nvidia-smi command returns the drivers 

=> cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() returns 1

Comment: On azure there is no such things, i thought you were configuring your own virtual machine. if cv2.cuda.getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()  returns 1, your gpu is correctly detected, and your opencv support this. All lights are green to unleash gpu power.

Comment: you must compile your python opencv wheel with the support of your specific gpu model and install it to your python environment. , how to do that??

Comment: maybe you can search on the internet or StackOverflow to see if this hasn't been answered :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223948/how-to-build-a-python-wheel-for-opencv

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to make it use CUDA and you should see a noticeable speedup. Check your Task Manager's Performance tab and see if your Nvidia GPU is being used. I don't know what's happening behind the scenes in my_function(), so I can't tell if there's something different in how you're using it.

This is the class that I usually copy around when I want a quick setup for the Yolo network

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

class Yolo:
    def __init__(self, cfg, weights, names, conf_thresh, nms_thresh, use_cuda = False):
        # save thresholds
        self.ct = conf_thresh;
        self.nmst = nms_thresh;

        # create net
        self.net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights, cfg);
        print("Finished: " + str(weights));
        self.classes = [];
        file = open(names, 'r');
        for line in file:
            self.classes.append(line.strip());

        # use gpu + CUDA to speed up detections
        if use_cuda:
            self.net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA);
            self.net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA);

        # get output names
        layer_names = self.net.getLayerNames();
        self.output_layers = [layer_names[i[0]-1] for i in self.net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()];

    # runs detection on the image and draws on it
    def detect(self, img, target_id = None):
        # get detection stuff
        b, c, ids, idxs = self.get_detection_data(img, target_id);

        # draw result
        img = self.draw(img, b, c, ids, idxs);
        return img, len(idxs);

    # returns boxes, confidences, class_ids, and indexes (indices?)
    def get_detection_data(self, img, target_id = None):
        # get output
        layer_outputs = self.get_inf(img);

        # get dims
        height, width = img.shape[:2];

        # filter thresholds and target
        b, c, ids, idxs = self.thresh(layer_outputs, width, height, target_id);
        return b, c, ids, idxs;

    # runs the network on an image
    def get_inf(self, img):
        # construct a blob
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 1 / 255.0, (416,416), swapRB=True, crop=False);

        # get response
        self.net.setInput(blob);
        layer_outputs = self.net.forward(self.output_layers);
        return layer_outputs;

    # filters the layer output by conf, nms and id
    def thresh(self, layer_outputs, width, height, target_id = None):
        # some lists
        boxes = [];
        confidences = [];
        class_ids = [];

        # each layer outputs
        for output in layer_outputs:
            for detection in output:
                # get id and confidence
                scores = detection[5:];
                class_id = np.argmax(scores);
                confidence = scores[class_id];

                # filter out low confidence
                if confidence > self.ct:
                    # filter by target_id if set
                    if target_id is None or class_id == target_id:
                        # scale bounding box back to the image size
                        box = detection[0:4] * np.array([width, height, width, height]);
                        (cx, cy, w, h) = box.astype('int');

                        # grab the top-left corner of the box
                        tx = int(cx - (w / 2));
                        ty = int(cy - (h / 2));

                        # update lists
                        boxes.append([tx,ty,int(w),int(h)]);
                        confidences.append(float(confidence));
                        class_ids.append(class_id);

        # apply NMS
        idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, self.ct, self.nmst);
        return boxes, confidences, class_ids, idxs;

    # draw detections on image
    def draw(self, img, boxes, confidences, class_ids, idxs):
        # check for zero
        if len(idxs) > 0:
            # loop over indices
            for i in idxs.flatten():
                # extract the bounding box coords
                (x,y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1]);
                (w,h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]);

                # draw a box
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 2);

                # draw text
                text = "{}: {:.4}".format(self.classes[class_ids[i]], confidences[i]);
                cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 2);
        return img;
```

You can use it like this

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# this is the "yolo.py" file, I assume it's in the same folder as this program
from yolo import Yolo

# these are the filepaths of the yolo files
weights = "yolov3-tiny.weights";
config = "yolov3-tiny.cfg";
labels = "yolov3.txt";

# init yolo network
target_class_id = 79; # toothbrush
conf_thresh = 0.4; # less == more boxes (but more false positives)
nms_thresh = 0.4; # less == more boxes (but more overlap)
net = Yolo(config, weights, labels, conf_thresh, nms_thresh, use_cuda = True);

# open video capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0); # probably laptop webcam

# loop
done = False;
while not done:
    # get frame
    ret, frame = cap.read();
    if not ret:
        done = cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q');
        continue;

    # draw detection
    # frame, _ = net.detect(frame, target_id=target_class_id); # use this to filter by a single class_id
    frame, _ = net.detect(frame); # use this to not filter by class_id

    # show
    cv2.imshow("Marked", frame);
    done = cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q');
```

Edit: Oh, ok, lol. I found my install notes and the very first instruction is this:

1. Follow PyImageSearch's Blog to install opencv with cuda support

The url is:

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/02/03/how-to-use-opencvs-dnn-module-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda-and-cudnn/

Not sure how helpful this will be, but I apparently thought the tutorial was clear enough that I didn't need any additional notes or corrections for this step.

Comment: Thanks !! Thats exactly the same logic as my function... Can you give some details about how you install opencv?

Comment: I've only ever built OpenCV with Cuda on Ubuntu computers. I'm not at all familiar with Azure VM's. I'll post my install notes here, but I can't guarantee that this will work for what you're using.